# How to update module path that is already installed? Odoo

Tags: python, database, module, path, odoo

I am looking for a way to update the currently installed module's path. I want to move the module from one `addons` folder to a different one and my attempt to just move the module and then `Update Modules List` gives me nothing. The module is not found and only a grayed out module name is left in the modules list.

Maybe there is a database table with all the paths already in it? And it is pliable to change?

**Update:**

I should mention that I have moved more than one module from its original directory to a different one and only a single module is not found. The rest work just fine.

Also, this has occurred more than once. I have restored a database from other server and while all of the modules should have been found among those set in `addons_path`, a single module was not (different one from mentioned before, although that one is present and recognized).

Answer (score 1):

In your `openerp-server.conf` file on line `addons_path` add your custom path, just put comma and place your path.

Restart server after that, update module list.

Comment: As I said before, my `addons_path` works as intended. I have moved more than one module in one go and the rest of the modules are found just fine. Just this one is not recognized.